# Не могу обновить приложение в play market'e

Tags: android-studio, android, google-play

Раньше я написал приложение на kivy и загрузил его в play market.
Сейчас понемногу осваиваю android studio, и в целом программирование под android.

Создал приложение, поставил новую версию 1.2.0 и в манифесте и `build.gradle` но никак не могу обновить приложение в маркете. Пишет:

> "Номер версии APK должен быть больше 101."

Причем если я загружаю просто на телефон через кабель, и в настройках смотрю — там версия стоит новая 1.2.0, но маркет почему то ее не определяет как новую.

Может где-то еще что-то прописать нужно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В андроиде 2 параметра отвечающих за версию: `versionCode` и `versionName`.

`versionName` - это строка обычно в формате "x.x.x". Это то, что показывает стор пользователю. Судя по всему, это то, что Вы меняете.

`versionCode` - это целое число, которое использует Google Play внутри для различения версий, и не показывает пользователю. При заливке каждой новой версии это число должно быть больше, чем для предыдущей (обычно на 1).

Подробнее [тут](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html) и [тут](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html).

Судя по всему Вы как раз забыли увеличить `versionCode`.

Comment: Спасибо получилось, а я считал что это чисто символический параметр, да я его и раньше крутил но безуспешно. Оказалось нужно было выставить его равным 102...